# Batch forecasting for multiple time series stored in columns using python ARIMA

Tags: python, time-series, forecasting

I am new to python time series. Not able to move ahead with this error. i want to forecast for multiple time series using ARIMA and store them in a dictionary or an array.

```
h=5
for i in range(len(t.columns)):
fc1= sm.tsa.ARIMA(t[:,i], (1,2,0))
fc2=fc1.forecast(steps=h, exog=None, alpha=0.05)
```

Comment: ile "<ipython-input-31-a6b69495bd61>", line 3
    fc1= sm.tsa.ARIMA(t[:,i], (1,2,0))
      ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is not with ARIMA, it is with your for loop. You're missing the indent that is required in Python.

Try:

```
h=5
for i in range(len(t.columns)):
    fc1= sm.tsa.ARIMA(t[:,i], (1,2,0))
    fc2=fc1.forecast(steps=h, exog=None, alpha=0.05)
```